# Creating back button to control WebView

Tags: java, android, webview

I have gone through so many stackoverflow answered questions about this, but nothing has worked for me. I want the android back button to control webview history. Every time I hit the back button in the emulator, the app closes.

This is my Activity that pertains to xml file containting my webview (id is myWebView):

```
    package com.example.inncwrestling;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BrandsActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.iframe_brands);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.wwe.com");

    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
  {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    /*Open SettingsActivity**/
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.menu_settings:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


}
```

I've been searching for a solution for two days now and I'm starting to think I'll have to view the source of an app like UberSocial.

I really need help and if it's not a problem, use my xml WebView ID 'myWebView'

Comment: when you run this are you clicking on any links in your webview? When your activity firsts starts there will be no pages in the history and thus `webView.canGoBack()` will be false which means that your back button press will close the activity. Before pressing the back button you'd have to click a few links inside the webview to build up a history of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Hiss,
you have done very fine work except this

> WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

here you dont have to declare myWebView again with WebView. Simple make it to

> myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

Now you will see your desired way of functioning.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the back button, onBackPressed() gets called in your Activity.  This gets called before any onKey event. Try overriding this method.

[onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)